# How to add + Key each time user click on space Key inside an Input

Tags: javascript, html, api, input

I created a Movie search Page using OMDB API. the issue I have is this API gives an error if I search for a movie that has more than one word bcoz the URL of API must have + key between each word in URL. so I would like to know how can i add the + key between each word when I click on space key in an input field. APi key is included so anybody can check for an error;

```
const url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=';
const apiId = '&apikey=gjhytjghjhg';
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const movieDtl = document.querySelector('.movie-detail');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let movieId = [];
let inputsearch;
let object;
let movieList;
let movieDetail;

input.addEventListener('keyup', getmovies);

function getmovies(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    inputsearch = input.value;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        getdatalist();
    }
   }
    xhr.open('GET', url + inputsearch + apiId, true);
    xhr.send();
 }
}

function getdatalist(){
    object = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    movieList = object.Search;
    movieList.forEach(function(e){
        movieId.push(e.imdbID);
        let list = document.createElement('li');
        movieDetail = '<img src="'+e.Poster+'" alt="Poster"><h4>'+e.Title+'</h4><button>View More</button>';
        list.innerHTML = movieDetail;
        ul.appendChild(list);
    }) 
         getdata();
}

function getdata() {
    let vwbtn = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');
    vwbtn.forEach(function(elem, index){
      elem.addEventListener('click', getListDetail.bind(null, index));
    })
}


function getListDetail(index){
    const secondurl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=';
    const mId = movieId[index];
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        let secObject = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        let detailList = '<div class="movie-detail-inside"><img class="movie-poster" src="'+secObject.Poster+'" alt="Poster"><div id="detail-wrap"><div class="layer-1"><h5>'+secObject.Type +' '+ '-'+' '+ secObject.Year+'</h5><h5> Released'+' '+secObject.Released+'</h5><h5>'+secObject.Runtime+'</h5><h5>'+secObject.Genre+'</h5><div><img src="star.png" alt="star icon"><h5>'+secObject.imdbRating+'</h5></div></div><h2>'+secObject.Title+'</h2><div class="layer-2"><h4>Production '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Production+'</span></h4><h4> Director '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Director+'</span></h4><h4> Writer '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Writer+'</span></h4><h4> Actors '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Actors+'</span></h4><h4 class="storyText">Story <br> <span>'+secObject.Plot+'</span></h4></div><div class="layer-3"><h4>'+secObject.Language+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Country+'</h4><button onclick="exitdetail()">Exit</button></div></div></div>';

        movieDtl.innerHTML = detailList;
        movieDtl.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
        }
     }

    xhr.open('GET', secondurl + mId + apiId, true);
    xhr.send();
}


function exitdetail(){
 movieDtl.style.transform = 'scale(0)';

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="search-div">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search movie">
</div>

<ul id="movie-showcase">
</ul>

<div class="movie-detail">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some URL encoding on the value in `inputsearch`. this is done by calling `encodeURIComponent`. See the code below:

> For reference URL encoding of a space is either `'+'` or `'%20'`.

```js
const url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=bcfe7e46&s=';
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const movieDtl = document.querySelector('.movie-detail');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let movieId = [];
let inputsearch;
let object;
let movieList;
let movieDetail;

input.addEventListener('keyup', getmovies);

function getmovies(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    inputsearch = input.value;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        getdatalist();
      }
    }

    var newUrl = url + encodeURIComponent(inputsearch);
    console.log(newUrl);
    xhr.open('GET', newUrl, true);
    xhr.send();
  }
}

function getdatalist(){
    object = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    movieList = object.Search;
    movieList.forEach(function(e){
        movieId.push(e.imdbID);
        let list = document.createElement('li');
        movieDetail = '<img src="'+e.Poster+'" alt="Poster"><h4>'+e.Title+'</h4><button>View More</button>';
        list.innerHTML = movieDetail;
        ul.appendChild(list);
    }) 
         getdata();
}

function getdata() {
    let vwbtn = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');
    vwbtn.forEach(function(elem, index){
      elem.addEventListener('click', getListDetail.bind(null, index));
    })
}


function getListDetail(index){
    const secondurl = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=';
    const mId = movieId[index];
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        let secObject = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        let detailList = '<div class="movie-detail-inside"><img class="movie-poster" src="'+secObject.Poster+'" alt="Poster"><div id="detail-wrap"><div class="layer-1"><h5>'+secObject.Type +' '+ '-'+' '+ secObject.Year+'</h5><h5> Released'+' '+secObject.Released+'</h5><h5>'+secObject.Runtime+'</h5><h5>'+secObject.Genre+'</h5><div><img src="star.png" alt="star icon"><h5>'+secObject.imdbRating+'</h5></div></div><h2>'+secObject.Title+'</h2><div class="layer-2"><h4>Production '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Production+'</span></h4><h4> Director '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Director+'</span></h4><h4> Writer '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Writer+'</span></h4><h4> Actors '+' '+'<span>'+secObject.Actors+'</span></h4><h4 class="storyText">Story <br> <span>'+secObject.Plot+'</span></h4></div><div class="layer-3"><h4>'+secObject.Language+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Country+'</h4><button onclick="exitdetail()">Exit</button></div></div></div>';

        movieDtl.innerHTML = detailList;
        movieDtl.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
        }
     }

    xhr.open('GET', secondurl + mId + apiId, true);
    xhr.send();
}


function exitdetail(){
 movieDtl.style.transform = 'scale(0)';

}
```

```html
<div id="search-div">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search movie">
</div>

<ul id="movie-showcase">
</ul>

<div class="movie-detail">

</div>
```

Comment: Intervalia. Thankx for help brother.